The level sets of the norm of a convex function's gradient
I am currently thinking about the following problem: Assume you are given a strongly convex $C^2$ function $f$. Consider the level set $E_c =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: ||\nabla f(x) || \leq c\}$.
Are these sets convex for any $c>0$? In the case $d=1$ this follows easily, since $\partial_x f$ is increasing monotonically as one moves away from the unique minimizer of $f$, though in the multidimensional case, I do not see an argument showing that the statement is true.
Any help is appreciated :-)!

Take
$$
f(x,y) = \frac45( |x|^{5/4} + |y|^{5/4}),
$$
with
$$
\nabla f = \pmatrix{ x^{1/4} \\ y^{1/4}}
$$
and
$$
\|\nabla f\|_2^2 = |x|^{1/2} + |y|^{1/2},
$$
so that $\{ (x,y): \ \|\nabla f\|_2^2 \le c^2  \}$ is non-convex for all $c>0$.

Thanks a lot for the reply! The function you defined is though not strongly convex but only convex. To recall the definition: We refer to a convex function as strongly convex if there exists $m>0$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d$ we have $(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^t (x-y)\geq m ||x-y||^2_2$. This does not hold for the function you defined as one finds when setting $y=0$.

Thanks again! Still, the three points you are comparing should not be a counterexample. Indeed, since (1,1) is the average of (0,2),(2,0), if we want to show that the level set is not convex, we would need to show that  the vice versa inequality to the one that you proved holds. Or am I a missing something?

What was I thinking. Not sure, how to repair this.
